# Insert initial values of parameters in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I have created a function to sort a list (selection sort) using recursive function. How can I insert  -- let i=0 and let j=i+1 -- inside this function?

```
let i = 0;
let j = i + 1;
function fSort(array) {
  if (array[j] < array[i]) {
    //  console.log("i=" + i + " j=" + j + " array=" + array);
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    fSort(array);
  } else if (j < array.length) {
    // console.log("i=" + i + " j=" + j + " array=" + array);
    j++;
    fSort(array);
  } else if (i < array.length) {
    //console.log("i=" + i + " j=" + j + " array=" + array);
    i++;
    j = i + 1;
    fSort(array);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Please pay attention to your tags: Java and JavaScript are different languages, and this is surely not Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to add a wrapper function that wraps the variables with the main function.

```js
function fSort(array) {
  let i = 0;
  let j = i + 1;
  function fSortInner(array) {
    if (array[j] < array[i]) {
      //  console.log("i=" + i + " j=" + j + " array=" + array);
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
      fSortInner(array);
    } else if (j < array.length) {
      // console.log("i=" + i + " j=" + j + " array=" + array);
      j++;
      fSortInner(array);
    } else if (i < array.length) {
      //console.log("i=" + i + " j=" + j + " array=" + array);
      i++;
      j = i + 1;
      fSortInner(array);
    }
    return array;
  }
  return fSortInner(array);
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work because the i and j will be 0 and 1 every time when the function restarts.